# Public property in blade component not found in view

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-10

Hi I am trying to make a simple blade component, but the public properties are not available in the view as the documentation says:

**Class**

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component
{
    public string $msg = "MSG";

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     */
    public function __construct(){}

    /**
     * Get the view/contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.returned-products.create-returned-products-form');
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<div>
    {{ $msg }}
</div>
```

**R: Undefined variable $msg**

I tried aso like this:

```
return view('components.returned-products.create-returned-products-form', [ 'msg' => $this->msg ]);
```

**But same result**
Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the [Passing Data To Components](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#passing-data-to-components) section of the the Laravel Blade documentation you mentioned it says:

> You should define all of the component's data attributes in its class constructor.  All public properties on a component will automatically be made available to the component's view.

It also includes an example showing that:

```
/**
 * Create the component instance.
 */
public function __construct(
    public string $type,
    public string $message,
) {}
```